# How to launch a EC2 instance and run a task on-demand

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, numpy, amazon-s3

We are developing an deep learning application on AWS. The automation of model training is quite challenging. The first step is to prepare the data for training which involves generating a huge 3D  numpy array (> 100GB) from hundreds of thousands of small 2D numpy arrays. The small numpy arrays are saved in S3 bucket as small files. After the conversion, the big numpy array will saved to another S3 bucket. The training script will pick up the big 3D numpy array before the training. Since lambda function has a memory limit so we will have to launch an EC2 instance manually.

I wonder what is the best practice to launch a EC2 instance from external and run the python script on the instance to do the data loading and transformation?

The whole workflow will probably be automated using AWS step function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with the most simple solution as this is not that complicated task (from the architectural perspective).

Configure S3 event for a bucket, the one where you are storing the new big 3D array, to trigger lambda function once the object has been put into the bucket (you can be more granular and trigger it based on prefix if you are storing all/different data in the same bucket).

Inside of that lambda function, you simply launch new EC2 instance and pass `user data` script to it that will download necessary files and run the task (this can be done using boto3 for Python).

Using CloudFormation in this case would be overkill (my opinion).

Comment: Actually things are quite automated already after the big 3D array is generated using `SageMaker`. It is the generation of the 3D array we want to automate which involves (1) start an EC2 instance with lots of memory (2) copy >100,000 files from S3 bucket to this EC2, (3) run a python script on the EC2 to transform the small files to a big one and (4) upload the final output file to another S3 bucket, (5) shutdown the EC2 instance

Answer (score -1):

You can use a Configuration set in a Cloud formation template to define steps where you can perform copies or run scripts or commands upon start up of your EC2 resource. You can even run it transiently so that it shut itself down after all operations are completed.

You can then use a script or Lambda function to execute the Cloudformation Stack

Comment: @WillEers It looks like boto3 has functions to start instance with ID, connect to it and execute a command. So potentially this can be done in a lambda. How does this method compare to the Cloud formation template?